# How does bash echo print its arguments?

Tags: bash, echo

According to `type` I use bash(4.2.37) built-in `echo`. Now if I type

```
echo 'Hello, World!'
```

..then echo command will see "Hello, World!" as a single argument? And in case of

```
echo Hello, World!
```

..the echo command will receive two arguments from bash? "Hello," and "World!" respectively.

Comment: Just read documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-commands_002c-shell

Comment: Yes, `echo 'Hello, World!'` passes one argument to `echo`, and `echo Hello, World!` passes two arguments. Was that really what you meant to ask? Are you confused by the fact that both commands produce the same output? Please update your question to clarify just what you're asking.

Comment: You seem shocked that `echo` is echoing the input you've given it.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was bit confused how echo handles arguments. Now I understand how echo behaves in case of single-quotes and without quotes. Still, what happens if I execute `echo "Hello, World!"` and have bash history expansion enabled? Am I correct that bash sees the !" part and tries to execute the history event(which fails, of corse) and `echo` is actually never executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` joins its arguments with spaces and prints the result.

This means that `echo Hello World`, `echo 'Hello World'`  and `echo Hello      World` all result in the exact same output.

If you want to see what would be passed as arguments, you can use `printf`:

```
$ printf "Arg: <%s>\n" Hello, World!
Arg: <Hello,>
Arg: <World!>

$ printf "Arg: <%s>\n" 'Hello, World!'
Arg: <Hello, World!>

$ var='my var
with linefeeds'    

$ printf "Arg: <%s>\n" $var
Arg: <my>
Arg: <var>
Arg: <with>
Arg: <linefeeds>

$ printf "Arg: <%s>\n" "$var"
Arg: <my var
with linefeeds>
```

`echo` output for the same would consist of each string in `<..>` with a single space between them.

Note especially that in the case of the unquoted variable, the resulting `echo $var` would not show the line feed (because `echo` sees four separate words that it just joins with spaces). There are daily questions about that on StackOverflow.